# Traduction de « heads-up »

Tags: traduction, expressions

Comment est-ce que l'expression anglaise « to give [someone] a heads-up » est traduite en français? Google Translate [propose « donner un heads-up »](http://translate.google.com/#auto/fr/give%20a%20heads%20up), mais on peut sûrement faire mieux.

Y a-t-il une bonne traduction de « heads-up » en français?

Comment: On peut dire "Je te/vous fais signe" ou même "Je te ferai signe" pour exprimer qu'on va donner de plus amples renseignements à l'avenir.  C'est plutôt "I'll let you know" que "heads-up," mais voilà.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bon si on [regarde la définition de](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+heads+up) « to give someone a heads-up », on peut remarquer qu'il y a plusieurs sens.

#### Avertissement

Si on veut utiliser l'expression dans le sens de « to give a warning » (donner un avertissement), je pense que l'expression la plus appropriée est :

> je voudrais vous *prévenir* de / autant te *prévenir*

On pourrait aussi utiliser « avertir »

> je voudrais *t'avertir* de …

#### Information

Si on veut utiliser l'expression dans le sens de « to give someone information », je pense que l'expression la plus appropriée serait « filer un tuyau »

> J'ai un *tuyau à te filer*

On peut aussi utiliser tout ce qui s'en rapproche tel que

> J'ai une *information à te transmettre*

Bref, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait vraiment une seule bonne réponse, tout dépend du sens qu'on veut donner à la phrase et de la personne à qui on s'adresse.

Answer (score -1):

"écoute"

ou

"fais gaffe"

suivant le contexte